# `Unsupported object type int` when passing a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` to tensorflow.convert_to_tensor()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I keep getting the error `Unsupported object type int` when passing a pandas `DataFrame` to `tensorflow.convert_to_tensor()`. I've already converted all columns to types supported by tensorflow. So I'm not sure why it's still not working. This is the dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 783 entries, 0 to 782
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------              --------------  ----- 
 0   gearbox             783 non-null    string
 1   fuel                783 non-null    string
 2   body_type           783 non-null    string
 3   sports_package      783 non-null    int32 
 4   mileage             783 non-null    int32 
 5   registration_month  783 non-null    int32 
 6   registration_year   783 non-null    int32 
 7   zip_code            783 non-null    int32 
 8   horsepower          783 non-null    int32 
 9   carplay             783 non-null    int32 
 10  accident_free       783 non-null    int32 
dtypes: int32(8), string(3)
memory usage: 42.9 KB
None
```

Here's the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[146], line 19
     13 x['accident_free'] = x['accident_free'].astype('int32')
     17 print(x.info())
---> 19 tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
     21 model.fit(x, y)

File ~/miniforge3/envs/tf_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File ~/miniforge3/envs/tf_projects/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:98, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97 ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Thank you for your help!

UPDATE: Here's the contents of the df:

```
  gearbox    fuel  body_type  sports_package  mileage  registration_month  \
0  manual  petrol  hatchback               0    26025                  12   
1  manual  petrol  hatchback               0    22987                  11   
2  manual  petrol  hatchback               0    13513                  12   

   registration_year  zip_code  horsepower  carplay  accident_free  
0               2021     86470          90        1              0  
1               2021     78628          90        0              1  
2               2021     14641          90        1              0
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data along with your script?